# How to allow endpoint to be called if request has specific header token using spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm using spring boot to build a web application, sometimes I ddont want to spend to much time on permissioning and rule management I just want to be able to create a random string token and allow other services to use my service if they know this token...

all know all the danger and problems related to this approach but for prototyping integration this is what i need...

the question is how can i configure spring security to validate a specific token for a specific endpoint [note that i want different tokens for different endpoints, if the thing was only 1 single token for the whole application se solution would be a simple filter]

EXAMPLE:

```
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
                  .csrf().disable()
                  .authorizeRequests()
                  .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/boards/").access("SOMETHING LIKE: httpRequest->headers->get('tokenHeader') == 'mytoken'")
    .anyRequest().authenticated() 
//......
}
```

I would like to achieve something like this....

The only way i'm able to do what i want now is by doing:

```
 @Value("${controller.plan.authorization}")
    private String AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN;
    
     @GetMapping
    public List<Plan> getPlans(@RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) authToken: String)  {
        if (AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN.equals(authToken))
            return planService.findAll()
        else
            throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "invalid authorization_token")
    }
```

which is quite out of spring pattern and really annoying in my opinion

is there any way to achieve that using spring security?

Answer (score 0):

So you have some common code which needs to be executed in the same way in multiple controllers and endpoints.

This makes interceptor a suitable solution.

Try the following

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Autowired
    private MyInterceptor myInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor).addPathPatterns("*/boards/*");
    }

}
```

Then the functionality you have described should be something close to the following

```
@Component
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Value("${controller.plan.authorization}")
    private String AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN.equals(requestTokenHeader)) {
            //continue execution in spring flow to reach the relative controller
            return true;
        } else {
            //break flow and return response.
            response.getWriter().write("invalid authorization_token");
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Now your controller can break free of that boilerplate code.

Comment: Why not a filter?